# 'TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON' with Express

Tags: javascript, json, express, knex.js

I use NodeJS and Express for my project and set it when the user login to index will keep the session value.

**req.session.user**

> { adminID: 3, username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }

And I want to get data from MYSQL so I use Knex like this.

```
router.get('/profile/user/me', (req, res, next) => {
    let user = req.session.user;
    if(user) {
        try {
            let me = req.session.user.adminID;
            let info = knex('admin_account').where('adminID', `%${me}%`)
            res.json(info)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/personal_information.html'));
        return;
    }else{
         res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

In my opinion, I think that if we are finished logging in, we will have a **req.session.user** I will use it to get data together with Knex.

Comment: What is your question here? Error most probably is thrown because of `res.json(info)` line.

Comment: @ViktorGusev I want to create an API for get information from each person but when test API is error according to the above topic

Comment: @Merphy what is the output of console.log(info), before res.json(info)?

Answer (score 0):

`req.sessions.user` and `info` may have the same value but arent the same type you should, first check the value of your variable info `console.log(info)`, there is a chance that you might need to `json.parse()` it or `json.stringify()` it if you want to send it as a response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query builder and wait for result before returning:

```
knex('admin_account').where('adminID', me)
  .then(info => {
    res.json(info)
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log(e);
  });
```

And you don't need `%` wildcards unless you are doing loose string comparison with `like` operator.

One more thing about the code is that you seem to try to return `res.json` and also `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/personal_information.html'))` at the same time, which doesn't make sense.